# Python, pip not properly configured

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a project that I have  pulled from git, and ever since I have not been able to use pip very much, but using the Pycharm setting to install works, even more than that, I'm able to import the packges to the project (Django rest framework) and use it.

But when i'm trying to migrate/runserver I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djoser'
```

```sh
venv $ pip3 install djoser 

output:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
```

This only apllies to the newly added packges and not the already used ones.

edit:
this error pops up few times as well:

```
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
```

Comment: pip install --user package try this.

Comment: No, don't! `pip install --user` might circumvent the virtual environment logic. From what you describe it sounds like your `pip3` is using the system `pip` and not the one from the venv. Try `python -m pip install`

Comment: tell us your operation system

Comment: @SiGNoR ubuntu 19.04

Comment: @FlyingTeller it raises the same error

Comment: do you change the python alias name? in ubuntu we have 2 types of python (python2 and python3). if you are coding in python3 , try: python3 -m pip3 install

Comment: it's better at first, you change your python3 and pip3 aliasses in terminal (.bashrc). and set them to "python" and "pip" and then try the: python -m pip install

Answer (score 1):

Had to go to a somewhat radical solution.

first, I uninstalled all pip that was on the system.

```sh
$ sudo -i
root ~# rm -f /bin/pip /bin/pip2 /bin/pip3
```

reinstall pip and OpenSSL

and for some reason that is not clear to me,

pip was installed properly to my machine's python 3.7 and not 3.8.

I decided to reconfigure venv and my project's interpreter to python 3.7 which fixed the problem.